# Migration warnings - Truncated key column length for column x to x - SQL Server to MYSQL Migration

Tags: mysql, sql-server, drupal-7, migration, mysql-workbench

I am using the migration wizard provided by MySQL workbench 6.3 to convert a SQL Server database into a MySQL. I tested the connection between both DBs and they are valid for the migration wizard. Once The migration wizard has completed I am left with 22 migration warnings and they are all the same warning:

> Truncated key column length for column 0 to 16

I am having a hard time finding any similarities between the tables that are receiving warnings to narrow down the issue. There are tables with the same types of data that are not receiving these errors.

Here is an example of one of the tables affected by this warning.

[image]

Does anyone know what is/what could be causing these migration warnings?

if you need more information/images please let me know.

Comment: Hello, did you find solution to this?

Comment: I'm also running into this issue, I haven't found a solution and this is followed by key issues during the migration process.

Answer (score 2):

Migration wizard show this warning when find index that have different length on source and target databases. In fact you should also get index name in that message - `... for column <name> from ...`, but it's empty. I guess something goes wrong, but to investigate that I need to reproduce issue on my machine. Please fill bug report on [bugs.mysql.com](http://bugs.mysql.com) and attach there sample database (you can make it private if you wish). Then paste link here.

Answer (score 0):

Warning doesn't matter. Just remember to rename the schema while migrating I have attached an image for better understanding

https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6PGK.png